# Jekyll doesn't find _layouts default.html

Tags: html, github, jekyll, github-pages

I just got started with Jekyll, I trying to get it working on my Github site, it loads all posts as it should but it doesn't load the _layouts default.html. As far as I know I have all of the necessary files.

[The Jekyll blog](http://abbe98.github.io/blog/)

[The source code](https://github.com/Abbe98/abbe98.github.com/tree/master/blog)

Anyone that can explain whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your `_config.yml` file from the `/blog/` subdirectory to the root directory of the repository, and then add this line to the file:

```
source: /blog/
```

Comment: When trying it I got the following email from Github: The page build failed with the following error:

page build failed

Comment: @Abbe you might also want to try using `./blog` as the source line in the `_config.yml` file. This would be more in line with how it works in the default configuration for Jekyll.

Comment: The source code is updated but still Jekyll fails to build. I'm on my school computer and it doesn't allow me to install ruby...

Comment: @Abbe There are multiple issues at play here, most of which are to do with storing your blog's contents in the `/blog/` subdirectory and how you've set up the `_config.yml` file to handle that. I've sent you a pull request with the changes you need to make.